# How to know which of two adapters is being used in ListView onItemClick?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView that is being populated (at different times) by two different custom ArrayAdapters (`AdapterA` and `AdapterB`). When a user clicks a ListView row I want to know which adapter is currently being used so that I can take the appropriate action and extract the data I need from that adapter.

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {

    if (isAdapterA) {
        // do something with AdapterA
    } else if (isAdapterB) {
        // do something with AdapterB
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to get a reference to and determine which adapter is currently populating the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(parent.getAdapter() instanceof CustomAdapterClass)
```

So the onItemClick method would be

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {

    if (parent.getAdapter() instanceof AdapterA) {
        // do something with AdapterA

        // If AdapterA were an ArrayAdapter of custom objects then
        // data from those objects could be retrieved like this:
        AdapterA adapter = (AdapterA) parent.getAdapter();
        String myString = adapter.getItem(position).getMyObjectData();

    } else if (parent.getAdapter() instanceof AdapterB) {
        // do something with AdapterB

        // If AdapterB were an ArrayAdapter of Strings then
        // they could be retrieved like this:
        String text = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the ListView has a Header? parent.getAdapter() returns HeaderViewListAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

If your ListView has a header, your

> parent.getAdapter()

will return an HeaderViewListAdapter and wont match AdapterA or AdapterB.

If you use Listview with header consider this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = ((HeaderViewListAdapter) ((ListView) parent).getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter();

if(adapter instanceof AdapterA){
   //Do something with Adapter A            
}else if(adapter instanceof AdapterB){
   //Do something with Adapter B            
}
```

If you don't use any Header, check the answer from Suragch.